# Calculate area of the surface $z = kxy/(1-x)$

Tags: definite-integrals, area, surfaces

Calculate area of the surface:
$$z = kxy/(1-x)$$
(https://www.geogebra.org/3d/uca6ehtc)

It's domain is restricted: $0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1-x$

$k$ is just a parameter controlling its streching. I need a formula or maybe an integral to calculate the area of the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula to calculate the area of a surface:
$$\iint_{S} dS$$
And you can find $dS$ as follow:
$$dS = \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2} dA$$

So you end up with the following formula:
$$ \iint_{S} dS = \iint_{D} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2} dA $$

And for your problem it's:
$$Area \space of \space z = \iint_{S} dS = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2} dydx $$

You can read this also for more explanations:
[MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v9.3to4](http://www.mit.edu/%7Ehlb/1802/notes-apm-jmo/pdf/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v9.3to4.pdf)